# How to Close Pupetteer Page if Parent Process (via Redis Queue) times out?

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, redis, puppeteer

Im spawning puppeteer sessions using subprocess.Popen to spawn node. However, the python process times out when the node job takes too long  (i'm using python RQ and it has built in timeout).

However, when this happens.. the python worker process dies normally but i can see that puppetter page is still running. The python worker is somehow "disconnected" from node (kill signal not being sent?)

I'd like nodejs / puppeeteer page to be killed (via timeout or keyboard interrupt). This is what I have, but puppeteer page is still visible when command line python process is Ctrl-C'd or when RQ times it out:

```
with Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) as process:
    try:
        print(process.pid)
        process.wait()
        stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

        print("stdout")
        print(stdout)

        print("stderr")
        print(stderr)

    except JobTimeoutException:
        pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        try:
            process.terminate()
        except OSError:
            pass
        process.wait()
    finally:
        # if process.poll() is None:
        print("process killed")
        process.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
        # stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```